# How to servlet println(); tag <c:forEach>

Tags: jsp, servlets, println

anyone have idea to slove my problem?

I need to use servlet to println the jsp like this.

```
<select name="users_province" id="users_province" class="form-control">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Province</option>
<c:forEach items="${provincesList}" var="lists" >
<option value="${lists.provinceCode}">${lists.provinceNameTh}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

This is my servlet code.

```
pw.println("<select name=\"users_province\" id=\"users_province\" class=\"form-control\">");
pw.println("<option value=\"0\" selected=\"selected\">Province</option>");
pw.println("<c:forEach items=\"${provincesList}\" var=\"lists\" >");
pw.println("<option value=\"${lists.provinceCode}\">${lists.provinceNameTh}</option>");
pw.println("</c:forEach>");
pw.println("</select>");
```

But my code print like this.

```
<select name="users_province" id="users_province" class="form-control">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Province</option>
<option value="${lists.provinceCode}">${lists.provinceNameTh}</option>
</select>
```

[My selectbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh57r.jpg)

Comment: My code not work at <c:forEach></c:forEach> tag.

Comment: Please state in what way your code is not working, e.g. the error message you are receiving

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically generate a jsp?

Comment: Yes, Maurice Perry.

Comment: @NayJeng not possible: your browser only understands plain html

Comment: Your problem statement is incorrect. You need to use a *JSP* to generate the *result* of the `<c:forEach>`.

Answer (score 0):

For this case i solve it by this code.

```
pw.println("<select name=\"users_province\" id=\"users_province\" class=\"form-control\">");
pw.println("<option value=\"0\" selected=\"selected\">Province</option>");
for(int i=0;i<provincesList.size();i++){
pw.println("<option value=\"" + provincesList.get(i).getprovinceCode() + "\">" + provincesList.get(i).getprovinceNameTh() + "</option>");
}
pw.println("</select>");
```