# href link inside modal thai language show "????????"

Tags: jsp, bootstrap-modal

From this question.

[How to servlet println(); tag <c:forEach>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670934/how-to-servlet-println-tag-cforeach/57681566#57681566)

I try to make daynamic modal by println in javaservlet.

I can fix it already, but i found all thai language show  like ???????.
I try to fix by use
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8") and response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") Or I try to fix with jsp. But  it not work.

**Here is my bootstrap modal code**

/employees

jsp code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Employees</title>
<jsp:include page="_header.jsp"></jsp:include>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal-dlg').on('click',function(){
        var dataURL = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.modal-dialog').load(dataURL,function(){
            $('#Modal').modal({show:true});
        });
    });
});
</script>
<!-- End Modal -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <jsp:include page="_menu.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div id="title_bar" class="btn-toolbar print_hide">

        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right modal-dlg" href="./employees/view"
            title="New Employee">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp</span>New Employee</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="_footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/employees/view = /view?type=employees

jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>

<form action="./employees/save_definition/-1" id="employees_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <div class="bootstap-dialog-header">
    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-close-buttom" style="display: block;">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title">ผู้ใช้ใหม่</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div id="required_fields_message">Fields in red are required</div>
   <ul id="error_message_box" class="error_message_box"></ul>
    <fieldset id="employee_basic_info">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_name" class="required control-label col-xs-3">Username:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_name" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_password" class="required control-label col-xs-3">Password:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_password" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="reusers_password" class="required control-label col-xs-3">Re-Password:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="re_password" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_gender" class="control-label col-xs-3">Gender:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_gender" id="users_gender" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Gender</option>
       <option value="1">Male</option>
       <option value="2">Female</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_name_title" class="control-label col-xs-3">Name Title:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_name_title" id="users_name_title" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Name Title</option>
       <option value="1">Mr.</option>
       <option value="2">Miss</option>
       <option value="3">Mrs.</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_first_name" class="required control-label col-xs-3">First Name:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_first_name" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_last_name" class="required control-label col-xs-3">Last Name:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_last_name" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_group" class="required control-label col-xs-3">Group:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_group" id="users_group" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Group</option>
       <option value="1">Administrator</option>
       <option value="2">User</option>
       <option value="3">View</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_address1" class="control-label col-xs-3">Address1:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_address1" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_address2" class="control-label col-xs-3">Address2:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_address2" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_city" class="control-label col-xs-3">City:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_city" id="users_city" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">City</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_state" class="control-label col-xs-3">State:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_state" id="users_state" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">State</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_province" class="control-label col-xs-3">Province:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_province" id="users_province" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Province</option>
       <c:forEach items="${provincesList}" var="lists" >
       <option value="${lists.provinceCode}">${lists.provinceNameTh}</option>
       </c:forEach>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_zip" class="control-label col-xs-3">Zip:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_zip" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_country" class="control-label col-xs-3">Country:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <select name="users_country" id="users_country" class="form-control">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Country</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_phone_number" class="control-label col-xs-3">Phone Number:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_phone_number" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
     <label for="users_email" class="control-label col-xs-3">Email:</label>
     <div class='col-xs-8'>
      <input type="text" name="users_email" value="" class="form-control input-sm" />
     </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer">
     <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons">
      <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

[image: Modal thai language show ?????]

You can see my bootstap table on employees not ploblem with thai language, but bootstap modal have ploblem with thai language.

Comment: I think the font used to bootstrap framework not support thai encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this problem come from **PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();** in my servlet code. But i don't known why.

viewServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/view" })
public class viewSerlvet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public viewSerlvet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        // Check User has logged on
            userAccount loginedUser = myUtils.getLoginedUser(session);

        // Not logged in
        if (loginedUser == null) {
            // Redirect to login page.
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
            return;
        }
        // Store info to the request attribute before forwarding.
        request.setAttribute("user", loginedUser);

        String errorString = null;

        Connection conn = myUtils.getStoredConnection(request);
        String typeQuerystring = request.getParameter("type");
        String definitionIDQuerystring = request.getParameter("definitionid");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        if (definitionIDQuerystring == null) {
            switch (typeQuerystring)
            {
            case "employees":
                List<provinces> provincesList = null;
                try {
                    provincesList = dbUtils.queryProvinces(conn);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errorString = e.getMessage();
                }
                request.setAttribute("provincesList", provincesList);
                break;
            case "customers":
                break;
            case "suppilers":
                break;
            case "stocklocation":
                break;
            case "categories":
                break;
            case "items":
                break;
            case "profile":
                break;
            default:
                response.getWriter().print("Invalid Parameter!");
                }
            }
            else {
                switch (typeQuerystring)
                {
                case "employees":
                    break;
                case "customers":
                    break;
                case "suppilers":
                    break;
                case "stocklocation":
                    break;
                case "categories":
                    break;
                case "items":
                    break;
                case "profile":
                    break;
                default:
                    response.getWriter().print("Invalid Parameter!");
                }
            }

        // Store info in request attribute, before forward to views
        request.setAttribute("errorString", errorString);

        // Forward to /WEB-INF/views/productListView.jsp
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/viewView.jsp");
        //        .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```